# Vertically align table of contents over two pages

Tags: table-of-contents

with a ToC that goes over two pages – how can I vertically align the right one with the left?

adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{10cm}}` (which I've copied and pasted from somewhere) only seems to work when it appears before a `\chapter`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SX! As a new member, it is recommended to visit the [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and the [Tour](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour) pages to be informed about our format and also to know about [Minimal Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228). 
Otherwise, more specifically about your question: A MWE will really help us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example using a standard class. Of course you have to adjust manually the vertical space every time you modify the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{chapter.tex}
\chapter{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\input{chapter}
\input{chapter}
\input{chapter}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}

\addtocontents{toc}{\null\vspace{4.5cm}}
\section{Title}
\section{Title}

\input{chapter}
\input{chapter}
\input{chapter}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: that's it — thank you!

Comment: You can avoid the placement problem by using \afterpage (afterpage package).  You probably still need \addtocontents with book class.